# How do various factors interact in preparation?

Tags: brewing-process, flavor, temperature

Obviously, differencies in a bunch of parameters yield variance in flavour and acidity? This is not only temperature, but also time (from the rapid espresso to Cezve to all-nighter cold brews), amount and grind.

There are quite a few discussions dedicated to some of them ([temperature](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/16/277), [water hardness](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/3/277), time for [espresso](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/415/277) and [french press](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/297/277), and even [the cup](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/385/277)).

I wonder if there are any interesting ways for them to interact. For instance, a coarser ground would take more time to get the result. Which other things can or cannot be rescued in this fashion? Say, get rich aroma if I only have light roast beans, etc.

I imagine that there is no short or definitive answer, but any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: This looks really broad. You may want to break it down in to a few, more direct questions.

Comment: This is a very broad subject which incorporates almost the entire purpose of this site in one question. Coffee preparation is about manipulating and controlling many many variables with countless nuances to affect the end result. I would suggest reading through the site and let us know if you have any *specific* questions about coffee preparation. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Ok, I agree. I'm narrowing it down, and if at some point I'm able to compile some sort of answer to the original broad version, I'll start a new question.